# Deep copy for Class with massive subclass in Java

Tags: java, class, object, clone

I have this class

```
class Cars implements Transport, Serializable, Cloneable {
   private String type;
   private Models[] cars;
   private int number;
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   Cars(String type, int number){
       this.type = type;
       this.number = number;
       cars = new Models[number];
       for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
           cars[i] = new Models("default"+i, Double.NaN);
       }
   }
    private class Models implements Serializable{
       private String model;
       private double price;
```

and i need to override clone() for deep copying this object with using super.clone(). How can i do this?

Comment: May be this helps you: https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy

Comment: no info about array structure copy :(

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-copy

Comment: Note that the `Cloneable` concept is considered pretty much obsolete and harmful, so if there's any way around it, use something else (like serializing, then re-deserializing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the easiest method to do deep copy is to add a copy-constructor to all your classes:

`Models` has only immutable attributes, so it's quite easy to create one:

```
public Models(Models other) {
    this(other.model, other.price);
}
```

Unfortunately `Cars` has also a mutable attribute (arrays of `Models`) so we need something different for copying this attribute:

```
public Cars(Cars other) {
    this.type = other.type;
    this.number = other.number;
    this.cars = Arrays.stream(other.cars)
        .map(Models::new)
        .toArray(Models[]::new);
}
```

Not only we create an new array, but each individual `Models` is also fresh new one. Note that this constructor relies on copy-constructor of `Models`.

So rather than calling `Cars cloned = (Cars) myCar.clone();`, you will just do:
`Cars cloned = new Cars(myCar);`

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something given in https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy

The clone() method will return you a shallow copy. You have to manually populate the mutable fields it this shallow copy with new objects. This will make your copy a deep-copy.